# Ansible to properly use powershell remote sessions

Tags: powershell, exchange, ansible

I'm trying to use ansible to create a mailbox on a remote server. For testing purposes, I will only try to "get a list of mailboxes" with "get-mailbox" instead of actually creating the mailbox.

I've tried lots of command combinations, but I think that it all ends up in the same issue regarding how powershell handles remote excecutions.

The issue is that in order to "get-mailbox", I need to load certain "cmdlets" in the powershell session which seems to be hard to do with ansible and for non exprienced powershell users like me.

This is my lastest attempt, which uses the "psrp" plugin for connection instead of the winrm. I'm not commited to this idea, it is just reflecting my latest attempt so far.

```
- name: prueba psrp
  hosts: servidor_exchange

  tasks:
    - win_shell: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -version 2.0 -NonInteractive -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ExchangeServer\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto ; get-mailbox"
  connection: psrp
  register: variable

- debug: 
    msg: "{{ variable }}"
```

The error message is too verbose to put it in the question description, so you can see it here https://pastebin.com/4E0vRmpX instead.

Here is another approach, where I try to configure the pssession manually.

```
- name: prueba psrp
  hosts: servidor_exchange

  tasks:
    - win_shell: |
        $username = "administrator@essi.ansible"
        $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Redhat01." -AsPlainText -Force
        $psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($username, $password)
        $sessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck
        Import-Module C:\PROGRA~1\Microsoft\EXCHAN~1\V14\Bin\RemoteExchange.ps1
        Import-Module C:\PROGRA~1\Microsoft\EXCHAN~1\V14\Bin\ConnectFunctions.ps1
        Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
        $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ansible-ex/powershell/ -Credential $psCred -Authentication Kerberos -AllowRedirection -SessionOption $sessionOption
#        Connect-ExchangeServer -auto
#        Get-Mailbox
      register: variable

    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ variable }}"
```

This won't even give me an error as most likely is waiting for some sort of user input that I can't see or even log (-vvvv) from my ansible host.

I guess the main problem is:
How to load modules/snapins and execute remote powershell cmdlets via ansible. In this case, it will be applied to creating an exchange mailbox, but I hope the same structure for remote excecution will work for maybe also using other powershell snapins/modules.

Thank you!

Comment: You're going to keep running into a kerberos double-hop problem.  In order to resolve this, you'll need to look at kerberos constrained delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to the remote Exchange Server and manage it, you could follow **Semicolon**’s workaround and check whether the session issue is fixed after that.

In addition, you could also refer to the official document "**[Connect to Exchange servers using remote PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/connect-to-exchange-servers-using-remote-powershell?view=exchange-ps)**" to run the following commands in the **Power Shell** to connect to your remote Exchange Server manually:

1. **Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned**(Run **Power Shell** as administrator)
2. **$UserCredential = Get-Credential**(Enter your **Admin UPN**)
3. **$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http:///PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential**(Replace the **ServerFQDN** with yours)
4. **Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking**

[image]

Or **automatically** connect to your server by entering your **Admin UPN**, **Password** and **Server FQDN** in the following script (**Test.ps1**):

```
$username = "<Your Admin UPN>"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "<You Admin Password>" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($username, $password)
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://<Your server FQDN>/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $psCred
Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber -DisableNameChecking
```

[image]

Then you could create and view your mailbox with the commands "**New-Mailbox**" and "**Get-Mailbox**":

[image]

[image]

Hope the above methods are helpful to you!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to review some of the options noted under the "Limitations" section of the Ansible guide to Windows Remote Management (WinRM): https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#limitations

Specifically:

> Credentials are not delegated for most authentication types, which causes authentication errors when accessing network resources or installing certain programs.

And the workaround:

> Set `ansible_winrm_transport` to `credssp` or `kerberos` (with `ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation=true`) to bypass the double hop issue and access network resources

Comment: After installing and configuring krb5 for the realm, I'm starting to face another set of problems derived by the use of kerberos itself. https://pastebin.com/j9EDmmfw Not sure if start troubleshooting this, as it feels like stepping away from the original issue. What would you suggest?